# Moving box2D body with texture?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I was following the solution from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180063/box2d-body-with-texture. I ended up getting this working for static bodies. But when trying to get the PolygonSprite to follow the body it is working but the textures scrolls as the body moves. I would like it to have a set texture and the UV's don't change.

[image]

As you can see by the top moving body the texture moves with the body but, the sprite is not staying constant. Every time draw is called the following is done. It recalculates the vertices and triangles.

```
    vertices = ActorUtil.calculateVertices(getShape(), body);
    short triangles[] = new EarClippingTriangulator().computeTriangles(vertices).toArray();

    region = new PolygonRegion(textureRegion, vertices, triangles);
    sprite = new PolygonSprite(region);

    polyBatch.begin();
    sprite.draw(polyBatch);
    polyBatch.end();
```

ActorUtil.calculateVertices

```
public static float[] calculateVertices(PolygonShape shape, Body body) {
    int vertexCount = shape.getVertexCount();
    Vector2 mTmp = new Vector2();
    float[] vertices = new float[vertexCount * 2];
    for (int k = 0; k < vertexCount; k++) {
        shape.getVertex(k, mTmp);
        mTmp.rotate(body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
        mTmp.add(body.getPosition());
        vertices[k * 2] = mTmp.x * GameInfo.CONVERSION;
        vertices[k * 2 + 1] = mTmp.y * GameInfo.CONVERSION;
    }

    return vertices;
}
```

EDIT: So, I did some more testing trying to figure this out and still couldn't get it. I found out that I only needed to compute Triangles once since the shapes never changed though.